# Como fazer aparecer o horário dentro de um HTML , usando um arquivo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu substitui uma tag do HTML lá no JavaScript com `.innerHTML`  ,dentro de uma função , porém olhando o resultado lá no site ,a var que tem `getHours()` não é identificada como var e fica escrito como texto. Já tentei colocar essa função no HTML ao invés do arquivo JS e não mudou nada, e também tentei colocar no `.innerHTML` o $`{new Date().getHours()}`, e também é identificado como texto.

Segue o código :

-no arquivo JS

```
function carregar(){
  var img =window.document.getElementById("img")
  var msg = window.document.getElementById("msg")
  var data = new Date()
  var hora = data.getHours()
  msg.innerHTML = "Agora são ${hora} horas"
}
```

-no HTML

```
<body onload="carregar()">
```

com

```
 <script src="APP/app.js">


</script>
```

dentro do

```
> <body>
```

--------Já tentei colocar dentro do `<head>`

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Acima no box azul tem um link sugerido, que tem a resposta. Sei que não parece ser a mesma coisa, pois no título ele menciona "somar minutos", mas isso é um pequeno detalhe que vc pode ignorar e adaptar pro seu caso. O importante é que o ponto geral (formatar o horário e colocar no HTML) está respondido lá

Comment: Entendido. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente formatar a data/hora assim:

```
// Obtém a data/hora atual
var data = new Date();

// Guarda cada pedaço em uma variável
var dia     = data.getDate();           // 1-31
var dia_sem = data.getDay();            // 0-6 (zero=domingo)
var mes     = data.getMonth();          // 0-11 (zero=janeiro)
var ano2    = data.getYear();           // 2 dígitos
var ano4    = data.getFullYear();       // 4 dígitos
var hora    = data.getHours();          // 0-23
var min     = data.getMinutes();        // 0-59
var seg     = data.getSeconds();        // 0-59
var mseg    = data.getMilliseconds();   // 0-999
var tz      = data.getTimezoneOffset(); // em minutos

// Formata a data e a hora (note o mês + 1)
var str_data = dia + '/' + (mes+1) + '/' + ano4;
var str_hora = hora + ':' + min + ':' + seg;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Olá ! eu já coloquei a new Date() e o data.getHours() em variáveis diferentes dentro da função , porém não entendi a parte de FORMATAÇÂO . Precisa colocar essa str_hora  em algum lugar?